# What might be causing Safari 6.0.2 to crash several times a day?

Tags: macos, safari, password

Safari 6.0.2 randomly crashes on me several times a day. Today I checked the console logs after it crashed, and only found this:

> objc[2339]: Object 0x7f9b7b41cab0 of class NSUserDefaults autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug

I'm running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2. Any ideas as to what may cause this, or can anyone point me to logs where I can find more information? This never happened before in OS X Lion.

**Update**
This issue occurred again a few days ago, and I few a more informative error message:

[image]

It appears to have been due to me having an older version of the 1Password Safari extension which had a bug with Mountain Lion. I thought I had the latest version because I had the latest version of 1Password installed, however to update the browser extension, you need to run the browser install again. I think [this](http://support.agilebits.com/kb/browser-extensions/safari-6-crashing-on-mountain-lion) may relate to the issue I experienced. I'll see how this runs for a few more days before declaring this as the true solution.

Comment: Please put the answer in the answer section. Even if you don't know it's right, it helps others see a potential answer instead of a question that is confusing (one with both Q and A in it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been due to me having an older version of the 1Password Safari extension which had a bug with Mountain Lion. I thought I had the latest version because I had the latest version of 1Password installed, however to update the browser extension, you need to run the browser install again.